# Paginate Sentry output in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

I'm using the parameters in my modules and it's all good, because I directly get a Eloquent Collection back.

But in the users module its a bit different, cause of the fact that I'm using the `Sentry 2` library.

How woudl I be able to pagina of those results?

At the moment I just have: `$users = Sentry::findAllUsers()`.
I can't call the `->paginate(10)` behind it because its not a Eloquent Collection..

Comment: you should still have a User model to use.

Comment: Well I'll just make my own mini User library, way easier with Eloquent when I set up the relations myself.